# How to use array in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

I'm trying to rename the NIC names on my PC. It has A LOT of NICs (they are virtual). I can get their names like so

```
for /f "tokens=2 delems==" %%A in ('wmic nic where "Description like 'foo'" get netconnection id /value') do (
 echo %%A
)
```

I'd like to use netsh inside that loop to rename them. Unfortunately, the target names aren't simple incrementing numbers. So I did

```
set names[0]=name1
set names[1]=name two
set names[2]=name test
set local ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a idx=0
for /f "tokens=2 delems==" %%A in ('wmic nic where "Description like 'foo'" get netconnectionid /value') do (
 echo names[!idx!]
 set /a idx=!idx!+1
)
```

This outputs

```
names[0]
names[1]
names[2]
```

But if I try

```
set names[0]=name1
set names[1]=name two
set names[2]=name test
set local ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a idx=0
for /f "tokens=2 delems==" %%A in ('wmic nic where "Description like 'foo'" get netconnectionid /value') do (
 echo %names[!idx!]%
 set /a idx=!idx!+1
)
```

I just get garbage output. Is there some way I can evaluate the generated string in the previous example as a variable? Then I could pass that to netsh to do the renaming.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Yes, that's the reference I used to get as far as I have before posting this question.

Comment: You are mixing up `Set /P` with `Set /A`. Second is the property is named `NetConnectionID` no space in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way to do this, but it only works when trying to index into an array of numbers. This is what I used

```
@ECHO OFF
set names[1]=101
set names[2]=102
set names[3]=103

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /a idx=1
for /L %%A in (1,1,3) do (
 set /a foo = names[!idx!] #This is the key, for some reason, an intermediate variable is required.
 echo !foo!
 set /a idx=!idx!+1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In first place, your code have a couple errors. This line:

```
set local ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

... should be written this way:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Otherwise the "setlocal" command becomes a "set" one, and don't works in the same way.

In this line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delems==" %%A in (. . .
```

... the option must be written "delims==" (NOT "delems=="), but in this case the FOR command issue an error.

After these errors were fixed, you should use the method to access array elements fully described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), so I copy the relevant parts here:

> To get the value of an element when the index changes inside FOR/IF,
>   enclose the element in double percent symbols and precede the command
>   with `call`:

```
call echo %%names[!idx!]%%
```

> Another way to achieve the previous process is to use an additional
>   FOR command to change the delayed expansion of the index by an
>   equivalent replaceable parameter, and then use the delayed expansion
>   for the array element. This method runs faster than previous CALL:

```
for %%i in (!idx!) do echo !names[%%i]!
```